# Point scoring algorithm for users based on article submission.

Tags: algorithms

There is a website where users contribute articles. User will score points based on the number of articles contributed. The point awarde should not be linear. The point score for each article contribution should diminishes as the number of articles increases.

For example:
1 - 10 contribution will be awarded 1 point each.
10 - 20 contribution will be awarded 0.9 point each.
20 - 30 contribution will be awarded 0.8 point each.

What will be the best algorithm for this?

Answer (score 0):

Something akin to $1-\frac{1}{n+\exp{-kx}}$ would work. Choose $n$ and $k$ based on what works, and find good breakpoints for your ranges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does x stands for? And here is n the number of articles and k the point?

Comment: $x$ would be the number of articles. $n$ and $k$ are tuning parameters.

Comment: thank you Arkamis, I will experiment with the tuning parameters.

Comment: Note that the function I gave you is continuous, and gives a different value for every different value of $x$. To adapt it for your needs, you'll need to do some experimentation and so forth and eventually you'll probably come up with something *ad hoc*. But generally speaking, you'll want a function of this form.